# Set curl options to improve readability of progress in R download.file()

Tags: r, curl, download

I am using R's `download.file(..., method="curl")` to download various text files.  The status updates from curl do not have a "\n" after each update, so what comes out looks like this, with no line breaks:

```
> url1 <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv"
> q1f <- "wk3q1f.csv"
> download.file(url1,q1f,method="curl")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0 4147k    0 18404    0     0  14232      0  0:04:58  0:00:01  0:04:57 14233  2 4147k    2  114k    0     0  51344      0  0:01:22  0:00:02  0:01:20 51341
```

Versions used: libcurl 7.30.0, R 3.1.0 for OS X.

Is there a curl option I can set for line breaks to make the progress report like so:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  
  0 4147k    0 18404    0     0  14232      0  0:04:58  0:00:01  0:04:57 14233  
  2 4147k    2  114k    0     0  51344      0  0:01:22  0:00:02  0:01:20 51341
```

I looked at curl-config and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option to make `curl` use `\n` instead of `\r` that I know of. However, you can do this on your own. This is an OS X specific answer, but can be adapted for linux. Using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) do a `brew install coreutils` so we can get access to `gstdbuf` which will help us get unbuffered command output.

Next, write a small shell script (I called it `mycurl`) with one line:

```
gstdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 curl $1 -o $2 2>&1 | gstdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '\r' '\n'
```

ensure it's executable (`chmod 755 mycurl`)

`download.file` just does the following if `method="curl"`:

```
else if (method == "curl") {
    if (quiet) 
        extra <- c(extra, "-s -S")
    if (!cacheOK) 
        extra <- c(extra, "-H 'Pragma: no-cache'")
    status <- system(paste("curl", paste(extra, collapse = " "), 
        shQuote(url), " -o", shQuote(path.expand(destfile))))
```

So, we can mimic it with:

```
status <- system(paste("/path/to/mycurl", shQuote(url1), shQuote(path.expand(q1f))))
```

Which will give you your download progress with newlines.

Linux users can juse use `stdbuf` vs `gstdbuf` since the `coreutiles` `homebrew` package prepends the `g` to the commands.

Alternatively, you could use `GET` from `httr` package with the `write_disk` option and use a more R-like progress meter:

```
library(httr)

status <- GET(url1, write_disk(path.expand(q1f), overwrite=TRUE), progress("down"))
|==================================================== (etc. to 100%)|
```